# How to remove phantom driver in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, drivers, windows-8-upgrade, windows-7-upgrade

We have Windows 7 Pro SP1 installed. We want to upgrade to Windows 8, but the upgrade fails. In D:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setuperr.log file there's only this:

```
2020-02-01 04:15:29, Error      [0x080902] MIG    InfEnumCallback: SetupGetInfDriverStoreLocationW failed for 'C:\Windows\inf\oem13.inf'[gle=0x00000490]
2020-02-01 04:22:34, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ee036dc0-f9b7-4d2d-bb94-3dd3102c5804}: BRIDGEMIG: CBrgUnattend::CollectBridgeSettings failed: 0x1, 0
```

But there's no C:\Windows\inf\oem13.inf file, no results after searching "oem13" or "ee036dc0" in registry.

How do we delete this phantom driver so we could upgrade the OS?

Comment: There is a oem13.inf on my w7 system, it is a Microsoft driver so you should have it. Manually look for it. It is a core printer driver. Try uninstalling any printer software You have installed.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely it is not the first error holding things up but the second error.

> BRIDGEMIG: CBrgUnattend::CollectBridgeSettings failed: 0x1

Try doing a clean boot in W7 then try upgrade again while clean booted.

Also disconnect any peripherals during upgrade, only mouse and keyboard connected.

[See this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows), Windows 7 section, on how to do a clean boot.